# Outputting records from form to Report

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am using a button to open a report based on a few filter selections and it is mostly working how I want it to although there are a few issues.

```
Private Sub cmdCreateReport_Click()

    On Error GoTo Err_cmdCreateReport_Click

    Dim stDocName As String

        If IsNull(cboLookUp) Then
            MsgBox "Please select a Supplier Region.", vbInformation, "Region required"

            Me.cboLookUp.SetFocus

        Else
            stDocName = "rptRegion"

            DoCmd.OpenReport stDocName, [acViewReport], Regions, _
            "[Region] = '" & Me.cboLookUp & "'" & _
            "and [txtAgreementID] = " & Me.cboAgreement & "" & _
            "and [IsActive] = " & Me.chkActive
            
        End If

Exit_cmdCreateReport_Click

    Exit Sub

Err_cmdCreateReport_Click

    MsgBox Err.Description

    Resume Exit_cmdCreateReport_Click

End Sub
```

1. The form itself doesn't display data but when I send to the report it displays. The form is blank but all the data is filtered almost correctly when exported as a report.
2. The second combo box is still asking for a parameter even though I have done it nearly the same as the first. The only difference is the second gets a number instead of text. When asking for the parameter it has to be entered as the selection but will display all active under that region.
3. The code to display the records in the form based on active or inactive is supposed to work by displaying only active or all. I want to make this the case in the report as well as at the moment it will display either active or inactive based on the checkbox ticked. Is there a way to add an If statement into the where condition or to call this line in order to get active if ticked or all if not ticked?
   `Like IIf([Forms]![rfrmRegionSearch]![chkActive],-1,"*")`
   The criteria in the Query to display active or all.

```
Private Sub cboLookUp_AfterUpdate()

    cboLookUp.Requery
    cboAgreement.Requery
    Me.Filter = "Region = '" & cboLookUp & "'"
    
End Sub

Private Sub cboAgreement_AfterUpdate()

    cboAgreement.Requery
    Me.Filter = "txtAgreementID = " & cboAgreement & ""

End Sub

Private Sub chkActive_AfterUpdate()

    chkActive.Requery
    cboLookUp.Requery
    Me.Filter = "IsActive = " & chkActive & ""

End Sub
```

The filter code for the two Combo Boxes and checkbox
cboAgreement is the combo retrieving a number

If there is any other information required please let me know.

Comment: By your first sub you are filtering data on report and that is cause it is working fine in case of report. To show filter data in form you need to apply it to form object. After `Me.Filter=.....` you can use `Me.FilterOn = True` or can use `DoCmd.ApplyFilter` method. Microsoft documentations are here [Me.FilterOn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.form.filter(property)), [DoCmd.ApplyFilter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.docmd.applyfilter)

Comment: Awesome. That has gotten the display part working however it is still asking for a parameter for `txtAgreementID` This is what the second combo should be providing

Comment: Can you try this please `Me.Filter = "txtAgreementID = " & CLng(Me.cboAgreement.Value)`

Comment: It still asks for an input and if I input the same value as I select it then displays all records even if active is ticked and other regions also

Comment: for troubleshooting purposes when combining strings print out the whole combined string.  the spaces before and are important here, For instance: change "and [txtAgreementID] = " & Me.cboAgreement & "" & _
            "and [IsActive] = " & Me.chkActive   to " and [txtAgreementID] = " & Me.cboAgreement  & _
            " and [IsActive] = " & Me.chkActive

Comment: You need a space in front of each `and` so compiled string does not run together. There is no need to concatenate an empty string. Why are you using the FILTER NAME argument?

Comment: @June7 Apologies as I am new but which is the FILTERN NAME argument? When I was trying to find how to filter this was the solution that was coming up a lot and it worked for the most part so it was what I went with.

Comment: It's the third one where you have `Regions,`. I have never used.

Comment: It filters the form where the textbox "Region" = the value i select in the combo box. At least that is what it should do.

Comment: Use one or the other: FILTER NAME or WHERE CONDITION. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/access/concepts/forms-design/apply-a-filter-when-opening-a-form-or-report?msclkid=928d2dbcd02711ec964c9fd38eeae803

Comment: The top one is for the report where the filter name is for the form. So change one or the other?